# Using send_password_email filter after wp_update_user

Tags: php, plugin-development, filters

I have created a custom plugin that will provide some custom user roles that are named `customers` and `operators`. When an user will create a new account, I've created some logics that imply that operators need to approve the new accounts. Using the `wp_insert_user()` I'm able to save new users into the database and thay will not get the login password to this step, after operators approval they will get a password generated using the `wp_generate_password()` function. At the moment, what I want to achive si to disable password change notification so the users will only get the emails I want to send them, so, a first email that will inform about the account status and the second that will give them the credentials after 24 hours from approval.

I've readed the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/send_password_change_email/) about `send_password_change_email` and it will be a lot clear about the filter. At the moment I have this code

```php
$password = wp_generate_password( 12, true, true );
//
$assigned_card_number = get_user_meta( (int)$customer_details['ID'], 'num_tessera', true );
//

    $user = wp_update_user( 
               array(
                'ID' => (int)$customer_details['ID'],
                'user_pass' => $password,
                'meta_input' => array(
                'account_details_sent' => true
               )
              ) 
            );
```

Can I call the filter after I've used the `wp_update_user` function and inside the same method?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the goal is. Are you trying to _not_ call `send_password_change_email` at all and use your own mailing method? Do you want to customize the `send_password_change_email` filter for your 24-hour window?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I need that the password change email isn't sended to the user when the system update the user meta informations. I will send to it the password in a separate email with other details registration. How I call the filter before `wp_update_user` function?